# Dynamically add variables to gtag's Javascript event paramaters

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-4

I am currently using GA4 to analyse our e-commerce results via the gtag purchase event. The structure in javascript should look as followed:

```
gtag("event", "purchase", {
  currency: "GBP",
  transaction_id: new Date().toISOString(),
  value: 3,
  items: [
    {
     item_name: 'A',
     price: 1
    },
    {
     item_name: 'B',
     price: 2
    }]
});
```

I have dynamically created the key value pairs for the `items` parameter in javascript using a string builder:

```
for (var i = 0; i < bookedItems.length; i++) {
  gtagItems += "{item_name: '"+bookingName[i]+"',price: "+Number(bookingPrice[i]).toFixed(2)+"},";
}
```

I have also used a string formatter to remove the last `,` in the string builder to ensure that the syntax is correct:

```
gtagItems= gtagItems.substring(0, gtagItems.length - 1);
```

Via the console log, I have confirmed that the builder has formatted the string correctly, but I am struggling to code it in correctly. My understanding of Javascript objects isn't what it should be, as the following code is not working:

```
gtag("event", "purchase", {
  currency: "GBP",
  transaction_id: new Date().toISOString(),
  value: gtagTotal,
  items: [gtagItems]
});
```

The string variables `gtagTotal` and `gtagItems` have already been defined, but when I test the code both `gtagTotal` and `gtagItems` displays empty.

As I said, my understanding of how to manage javascript objects isn't what it should be. I believe the problem is with how I am inserting the variables into the gtag code.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `gtagItems` needs to be an array of objects

```
var gtagItems=[];
for (var i = 0; i < bookedItems.length; i++) {
  let item = {
    'item_name': bookingName[i],
    'price': Number(bookingPrice[i]).toFixed(2)
  }
  gtagItems.push(item)
}
```

Then pass it as

```
gtag("event", "purchase", {
  currency: "GBP",
  transaction_id: new Date().toISOString(),
  value: gtagTotal,
  items: gtagItems
});
```

PS: You haven't showed the working of `gtagTotal` variable, so its hard to say whats wrong with your total